# Downgrade From Windows 10 after Changing Administrator Password

Tags: windows-10, downgrade

After installing Windows 10, I changed my Administrator account password, losing my EFS-encryption on some system files according to this fine print which I didn't read in my haste to make sure I had a working password:
[image]

Now, I can't downgrade because it keeps giving me the error when trying to downgrade that I need to remove Administrator (even though I restored its de-activated state through "net user Administrator /active:no" command).
[image]

If anyone has any solution at all... I will try anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this'll work, but I think it is failing because it still finds the profile on your computer.

The following steps are for windows 8 (can't test it on 10 right now, but I bet they're nearly the same)

1. Right click start button
2. Select Control Panel
3. Open System
4. Choose Advanced System Settings
5. Under tab `Advanced`, Frame `User Profiles`, press <kbd>Settings...</kbd>
6. Select the user and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Comment: Wow! What a bold solution! It works! :) thank you

Comment: Never mind... This allowed the downgrade but I am stuck in a BSOD login screen boot loop. I will have to reformat and reinstall everything.

Comment: I can't do anything about that, but that still makes my answer the solution to your question. Why did you unaccept it?

Comment: Is it a legitimate solution? Let me see if it was a driver issue.

Comment: I can go into safe mode by normal start up goes into a Loop with black screen and wifi icon looping where logon screen is supposed to come... [Any ideas?](http://superuser.com/questions/957685/windows-10-downgrade-bootloop)

Comment: Yes it was a [driver issue](http://superuser.com/questions/957685/windows-10-downgrade-bootloop).