# Windows 10 downgrade bootloop

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod, windows-10, safe-mode, downgrade

I downgraded to Windows 8.1 according to [this answer's](https://superuser.com/questions/957514/downgrade-from-windows-10-after-changing-administrator-password/957518?noredirect=1#comment1307750_957518) advice.

Now, whenever I start my computer I am stuck seeing a bootloop of a black log-on screen. I can also see my mouse cursor which moves back to original location after my wifi icon on blinks 3 seconds of attempting to process. Everything else is blacked out except my mouse and wifi icon.

I can still go into Safe Mode. Is there something I can do to fix this? I will even go back to Windows 10 if that will not make things even worse.

Comment: If you can get into safe mode can you go into the Event Viewer (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools) and see if there are any suspicious entries in the System logs?

Comment: "A pointer device reported a bad angular physical range" is the most frequent, occurring while the BSOD occurs

Comment: Well that's a strange error, which makes me think that this is a laptop  with touchpad or touchscreen.  Can you try uninstalling any drivers for your touchpad either via the normal remove programs control panel or via Device Manager?

Comment: Omg moksha I I I had just done that... Thank you for your line of inquiry. Please post an answer saying the above so I can select it as the solution.

Comment: I'll post an answer while you edit the error message you saw into your question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your error message

```
A pointer device reported a bad angular physical range
```

It suggests that somehow your touchpad driver is either corrupted or somehow has not up/downgraded successfully.

I would recommend uninstalling any drivers for your touchpad either via the normal `remove programs` control panel or via Device Manager and reinstall them from your manufacturer.

Comment: Nicely done Mokubai. :)

Comment: @LPChip just happened to be in the right place at the right time.  Apart from me suggesting Event Viewer it sounds like Ahmed had it under control.

Comment: Yeah it was the 2ndary display auto installing an incompatible driver. I used to have the same problem before but never to the point that it would BSOD. And it would always be fine after I installed the Lenovo driver. I've tried uninstalling the display driver and installing every driver I could find including the Lenovo driver.. Even the last driver that worked fine prior to win 10 when I install instantly goes into The BSOD described... And there's a lot of things in the event viewer some of which indicates other driver issues..

Comment: Reverting to the basic display driver works fine but I can't use any external display.

Comment: No matter how much I wish, I think the downgrade screwed up too many drivers.. I'll have to reformat...

Comment: I was going to say it does sound a bit like there is some underlying fatal problem with your install of Windows 8.  Were you fine with Windows 10?  Was the reason you needed to downgrade the EFS issue, and if that is now resolved is re-upgrading an option?

Comment: @mokubai quick question.. I put all my files and some program files on an external HD connected by SATA but my main OS on an SSD.. How do I know if after I reformat I would be able to access all those external files? If not how can I make them accessible after I reformat my SSD is? I need to be able to access this SATA drive after I reformat my OS... Which contains about 1tb of files some of which are Program Files..

Comment: You *should* be able to access those files fine if you copy them to an external drive. If the drive is formatted NTFS then it *might* tells you that you don't have access to them then as your user credentials might not match, but long as you have at least one user with administrative rights on the laptop that that hard drive is connected to (which you *will* have) then if you will be able to "claim" those files as "yours" and regain access to them, unless they are encrypted.  I would personally backup anything you care about to that drive and disconnect it while you reinstall.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27007/discussion-between-mokubai-and-ahmed).